# Is there solution available to create a SMB/CIFS "server" on iOS/tvOS/watcOS using swift or objective C

Tags: swift, objective-c, server, share, smb

I need to create a LAN server on iOS device and give write access to the client device. Is there any library or resource available to create SMB server on any iOS/macOS/tvOS/watchOS but using swift that i can use or work on to create a working SMB server on any of iOS/tvOS/watchOS. I have tried to create an http server but for reasons(Apple) I am not able to give write access and i can only give read access for files. I also know that there are SMB client libraries out there like AMSMB2 & TOSMBClient. But i need a server on a non macOS device. I am trying to do that using SMB right now if possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaloop has an SMB server/client for iOS

Comment: If you are refering to ```https://github.com/Pentaloop/PLWebServer``` then it does not mention SMB... Also it is HTTP which is not what I am looking for...

Comment: ```https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer``` would be a better solution for Http as it is well documented and maintained until the start of this year.

Comment: I am not sure this is the project, as I believe the SMB library product is not an open-source solution.